# Android Views and Screen Orientation

Tags: android, user-interface

Is it possible to have two Views in Android; one of which is the "background" and wont rotate when the device is rotated. And have the other one on top (the "UI-elements") rotate on orientation change?

I know I can disable/enable orientation changes for a whole activity but how would I go about that for separate Views in one activity?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's possible, but usually to support "landscape" and "portrait" orientations, you would create another folder in your "res" folder and call it "layout-land" then copy your .xml file in "layout" to "layout-land" and make the appropriate changes to your UI-elements.

If you want to keep the background the same, then I suppose you can leave it unchanged or you might have to rotate the image and save a copy of the rotated image to use in landscape orientation.

Hope that's helpful!